# get all stand alone FILES

Tags: files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have a process of case auto deletion, and it seems that when a case is deleted and a file was attached to it, the file is not deleted in the same time.

Q1: Is it possible that files remains in SF but not linked to any entity?
Q2: if yes how can I retrieve those files? I tried with simple SOQL but there are limit in on semi join object

```
select id from ContentDocument where id NOT IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink)  order by CreatedDate limit 1000
```

I also tried to write a script without success

any idea?

Comment: this is tricky because ContentDocuments (file) could also be associated to users, libraries, other records, groups, etc.